# springboot h2 fails to create db and to login into h2-console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am using spring boot and maven to build my user Onlineshop. I would like to access my h2-console database *onlineshop* but I am failing to login with everything left as default. Also the database *onlineshop* is not created. Spring Boot is not throwing any errors since am using embedded tomcat.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
<artifactId>h2</artifactId>
<version>1.4.199</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Is that the URL you are trying to connect?

Comment: No, I am connecting to  http://localhost:8080//h2-console  but once it fails that url is generated automatically

Comment: Try changing your JDBC URL to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`

Comment: `jdbc:h2:mem:testd` gives same error

Comment: I think you may remove the spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop from properties file because spring boot enables auto configuration

Comment: In your properties file replace `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop` with `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop;IFEXISTS=FALSE` @Odwori

Comment: same problem even after `...:h2:mem:onlineshop;IFEXISTS=FALS` and after removing `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop`

Comment: @Odwori set below properties as in answer

Comment: For information: the error message in 1.4.198/1.4.199 is not correct, the upcoming 1.4.200 will have a better message. H2 Console in such configuration does not allow creation of new databases. The database must be created by application itself first and only after it the database will be accessible by embedded H2 Console. Of course, there is no reason to add `IFEXISTS=FALSE`, it can't override the security settings.

Comment: I have solved it by simply going for lower version of com.h2databse `<version>1.3.170</version>`. Thanks all for your willingness to help

Answer (score 2):

Set below properties in the `application.properties`

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:onlineshop;IFEXISTS=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

***[IFEXISTS](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists)***

> By default, when an application calls DriverManager.getConnection(url,
>   ...) with embedded URL and the database specified in the URL does not
>   yet exist, a new (empty) database is created. In some situations, it
>   is better to restrict creating new databases, and only allow to open
>   existing databases. To do this, add ;IFEXISTS=TRUE to the database
>   URL. In this case, if the database does not already exist, an
>   exception is thrown when trying to connect

Comment: with this answer localhost:8080//h2-console displays error

Comment: @Odwori please add `spring.h2.console.enabled=true`

Comment: can you clean and rebuild the project if it does not help then remove `spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console`

Comment: can you update the question with the application file to see updated properties with last error message or image

Comment: I have solved it by simply going for lower version of com.h2databse `<version>1.3.170</version>`. Thanks all for your willingness to help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply downgrading the com.h2database

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.170</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```